# Need get proper sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got issue with making proper sql query. Firstly i got like auto parts factory where people create and register each part. All users who have made atleast once that part with this model should be listed. What i need is table which gives me:

Columns:

User id <--- user id who is crafter part depending on part model.

Shortest time of making part <--- from all records with that user id choose shortest duration.
(loop thought each row with that user id and find)

Longest time of making part <--- from all records with that user id choose longest duration.
(loop thought each row with that user id and find)

Average time of making part <--- add all records duration with same user id and divide from all records count.

Count of parts <--- how many parts made of that model this user.

---

Now i have sql statemet which gives me all not grouped workers who have made that part.

```
SELECT dd.user_id AS user_id,dar.name AS name,    
dar.surname AS surname,dd.duration AS duration     
FROM tblPart AS d    
INNER JOIN tblUserPart ON dd ON d.part_id = dd.part_id    
INNER JOIN tblUser AS dar ON dd.user_id = dar.user_id    
WHERE d.part_model='SST32KTF'
```

DATA with this sql:         http://postimg.org/image/i3w663b1b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't homework is it? This gives durations in seconds. Let me know if you need to convert back to HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT 
dd.user_id AS user_id,ar.name AS name,dar.surname AS surname,
MAX(
(DATEPART(HOUR, dd.duration) * 3600) +
(DATEPART(MINUTE, dd.duration) * 60) +
(DATEPART(SECOND, dd.duration))
) AS maxduration, 
MIN(    (DATEPART(HOUR, dd.duration) * 3600) +
(DATEPART(MINUTE, dd.duration) * 60) +
(DATEPART(SECOND, dd.duration))
) AS minduration, 
AVG(    
(DATEPART(HOUR, dd.duration) * 3600) +
(DATEPART(MINUTE, dd.duration) * 60) +
(DATEPART(SECOND, dd.duration))
) AS avgduration, 
COUNT(*) As PartsCount
FROM tblPart AS d    
INNER JOIN tblUserPart ON dd ON d.part_id = dd.part_id    
INNER JOIN tblUser AS dar ON dd.user_id = dar.user_id    
WHERE d.part_model='SST32KTF'
GROUP BY dd.user_id,ar.name,dar.surname
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',dd.duration)`?

Comment: cut n paste error from his original SQL. AVG on a TIME datatype? :)

Comment: I was suggesting it might be a more reasonable way of calculating the length of a duration in seconds, rather than by manually extracting each component and performing maths on them.

Comment: Oh I see. Your expression is shorter and simpler than mine - fair enough, that's true.

Comment: Yes, looks like now left last step to convert into time() again

Comment: ElectricLlama, which function converts back to string?

Comment: Using Damian's expression which is a bit simpler, note that in this case, DATEDIFF finds the difference in seconds and returns a number. How do you get back? you use DATEADD. I will edit the answer shortly.

Comment: Actually... to get the largest TIME value you can just use MAX on it directly. So simply replace the first column with `MAX(d.duration) AS maxduration,` The AVG will still have to be done in seconds. Using @Damiens suggested expression: `CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(S,AVG(DATEDIFF(s,'00:00:00',d.duration)),'00:00:00')) As AvgDuration`

Answer (score 2):

You don't (generally) have to write loops yourself in SQL. You tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*:

```
SELECT dd.user_id AS user_id,dar.name AS name,    
dar.surname AS surname,minD,maxD,avgD,Cnt
FROM tblPart AS d    
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       part_id,user_ud,
       MIN(duration) as minD, MAX(duration) as maxD,
       AVG(duration) as avgD, COUNT(*) as Cnt
    from tblUserPart
    group by part_id,user_id) dd ON d.part_id = dd.part_id    
INNER JOIN tblUser AS dar ON dd.user_id = dar.user_id    
WHERE d.part_model='SST32KTF'
```

---

References: [`MIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx),[`MAX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx),[`AVG`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx),[`COUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

---

Having looked at your image, I now see that `duration` in your model is being stored as `time`. This is *not* an appropriate use of the `time` data type. `time` is intended for storing a *time of day*, **not** an interval. There's not really a good data type for storing intervals, currently, in SQL Server. The best approach would be to store `duration` in an `int` column and probably rename it as `durationMins` or `durationSecs`. Keeping it as a `time` column will probably cause you more issues in the future.

To convert it, on the fly, to a duration in minutes use `DATEDIFF(minute,'00:00:00',duration)`, for seconds use `DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',duration)`, wherever I've used plain `duration` in the above query.

Comment: I`m getting : Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator.

Comment: @KarolisSemaška - have you read the third block of my answer? I'd suggest that a permanent change be made to your tables because `time` is not an appropriate data type to use here. But, if you don't want to make this change at this time, you need to substitute `DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',duration)` wherever I have `duration` in the original query.

Comment: should i do something like creating new column in table and loop through each table row depending on duration value add into new table DATEDIFF(minute,'00:00:00',duration) ?

Comment: You can add a new column, e.g. `durationMins int` and then `UPDATE tblUserPart SET durationMins = DATEDIFF(minute,'00:00:00',duration)`. Again, you don't generally write loops in SQL. You express what you want to achieve for the entire set of rows.

Comment: Also this sql doesnt groups rows by user id